# Translate result to Yes or No while querying boolean field in elastisearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I am having field mapping which is of type boolean and indexed data is true or false. When I query data, It returns true or false but I want to translate it to Yes if the value is true and No if the value is false or empty.

I searched on Google and found the runtime-mapping method https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html but we are using ES 7.10.2 (JAVA) version which does not support this method.

Any other way without changing indexed data we can get Yes or No value in the query result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/search-fields.html#script-fields).

```
POST my_index/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{ "my_boolean_field": true }
{ "index": { "_id": "2" } }
{ "my_boolean_field": false }
{ "index": { "_id": "3" } }
{ "my_boolean_field": true }
{ "index": { "_id": "4" } }
{ "my_boolean_field": null }

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "translated_bool": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['my_boolean_field'].size() == 0 ? 'No' : (doc['my_boolean_field'].value == true ? 'Yes' : 'No')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]